# How can I change the names of multiple columns in r using paste0

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which has 50 columns and I am trying to change the name of half of the columns to include the word "female_" in the title. What code can I use to change the name of multiple columns?

Comment: how can you identify these 25 columns?

Comment: Perhaps, a different question:  Why do you want to do this?   I would have thought that holding the gender in a separate column would be easier for further analysis than embedding the data into the another column ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` is vectorized.  So, it can be directly changed with concatenating a string into it and updating the relevant column names

```
names(df1)[1:25] <- paste0("female_", names(df1)[1:25])
```

NOTE: Here, we are taking the first 25 column names (as the position is not specified)